# mergExt - mergAV - create movie from images?

Tags: avfoundation, livecode

Anyone know if it's possible to create a movie from a series of still images and audio using mergAV in LiveCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible. There's a couple of different way the feature could be added to mergAV though...

Comment: Look forward to that at some stage. Thanks!